# 2d arrays and how to populate them with one dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays

This is my code:

```
def SetUpScores():
  scoreBoard= []  
  names = ["George", "Paul", "John", "Ringo", "Bryan"]
  userScores = [17, 19, 23, 25, 35]
  for i in range(0,5):
    scoreBoard.append([])
    for j in range(0,2):
      scoreBoard[i].append(names[i])
      scoreBoard[i][1]= userScores[i]
```

I'm basically trying to create a two dimensional array that holds the name and the userScore, I have looked this up alot and so far I keep getting the error of list assignment index out of range or 'list' cannot be called.

If i remove the last line from my code i.e:

```
def SetUpScores():
  scoreBoard= []  
  names = ["George", "Paul", "John", "Ringo", "Bryan"]
  userScores = [17, 19, 23, 25, 35]
  for i in range(0,5):
    scoreBoard.append([])
    for j in range(0,2):
      scoreBoard[i].append(names[i])
```

I get

[['George', 'George'], ['Paul', 'Paul'], ['John', 'John'], ['Ringo', 'Ringo'], ['Bryan', 'Bryan']] without any errors (this is just to test if the array was made).

I would like to make something like:

[['George', 17], ['Paul', 19], ['John', 23], ['Ringo', 25], ['Bryan', 35]]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the line `scoreBoard[i].append(names[i])`, you add a single element, not a list. So, the next line `scoreBoard[i][1]= userScores[i]` causes an error, because it refers to the second element of `names[i]`, which is just a string.

The most compact way to do what you want would be

```
for name, score in zip(names, userScores):
    scoreBoard.append([name, score])
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, this helped so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
names = ["George", "Paul", "John", "Ringo", "Bryan"]
userScores = [17, 19, 23, 25, 35]
L3 =[]
for i in range(0, len(L1)):
    L3.append([L1[i], L2[i]])

print(L3)

Output:
[[17, 'George'], [19, 'Paul'], [23, 'John'], [25, 'Ringo'], [35, 'Bryan']]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also very helpful as I'm quite new to python!

Comment: @ShannonR me 2, first I hated this language but I've learned to respect it.